# How to extract text from a string in excel based on a list

Tags: google-sheets

I have a string which may look like : 
"The Ford dealership" and another cell that says "The Tesla store"

I used

```
=iferror(Regexextract(A2,"Ford","Tesla","Toyota","Hyundai"))
```

and the return is Ford for the first string which is correct.

However when I run it on the second string the output is empty.

What I want to do is basically say if exists Regexextract Ford or Tesla or Toyota or Hyundai from the cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't use Excel tags for questions specifically about Google sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex symbol for OR is `|` so your formula should actually read like this:

```
=iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"Ford|Tesla|Toyota|Hyundai"))
```